# How to handle tcl expect output

Tags: tcl, expect

I am writing an expect script to telnet to the router ,do some config,expect some output.

If the required prompt is not available then it waits for it and gets time out.
So how do i have to handle this and print an error msg.

```
set timeout 30;

puts "Telnet to $IP 2361\n\n";
spawn telnet $IP 2361;

expect ">";

send "ACT-USER::$user_name:1::$password;";
expect ">";
```

How do i handle and print an error msg if the expected value is not received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dealing with timeouts nicely requires a slightly more complex use of `expect`:

```
expect {
    ">" {
        # Got it; don't need to do anything here because we run the code after
    }
    timeout {
        send_user "timed out, oh no!\n"
        exit 1
    }
}

# Now we put the rest of the script...
send "ACT-USER....blah"
# ...
```

Note that I'm surprised that your `send` doesn't end in `\r` (to simulate pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key).

Comment: `send "Pollers\r"
expect ">"`
after executing above line i am getting some lines in CMD like below.
`"Client" Pollers
1) "ICTS_ICEFIX_Worker Worker" (ICTS_ICEFIX_Worker Poller): RUNNING
2) "NYMEX UTBAPI Worker" (NYMEX UTBAPI Poller): STOPPED
Enter a poller number or any other key to return to the parent telnet session:`
these above lines i want to store in one array variabe and then i want to read line by line and check if NYMEX word is there or not. if there then i need to cut the substring from that line and store the number, NYMEX UTBAPI and UTBAPI in one hash array to do further process.